# Flutter freezes system(ubuntu)

Tags: android, ubuntu, flutter

when i use **everything related to flutter**,**even flutter doctor** or **even when i open my flutter project folder with IDE**,when my system is not plugged into charger **it'll freezes after 2 or 3 seconds** even **Alt + sysrq + REISUB does not work** for me

actually i guess this 2,3 second delay its maybe related to **android studio**,because my flutter doctor output **passed first step** which is:`[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)`
**and then my system freezes while flutter doctor command is running in terminal** just in Android toolchain step

BTW,i was using **ubuntu 18.04** and cause i had this problem i've decided to upgrade it to **18.10** and actually nothing has changed

i'll be so glad if any one could help me through this,*cause i'm seriously thinking of reinstalling my OS*

Comment: cpu? system logs?

Comment: I'd do some research online and include that in your post. Have other users experienced similar issues? If so what did they do to address it? 

It sounds like your very frustrated, but if you can edit you question to only include the necessary information to help understand you problem that will make it easier to answer.

Comment: actually, I've found one other user experiencing a similar situation but his problem was still open @DavidArgyleThacker

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of searching and also checking my system's logs I've failed to solve this problem, I have **reinstalled ubuntu** because of some problems I have seen using Ubuntu. exactly at that period of time flutter suddenly released **flutter 1.2 SDK**, now everything is working fine and I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with flutter 1.2 (**still, I think that the problem was not Flutter, and It was because of android studio**)